# Highlight Text Lines Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I've search to no avail. I want to highlight certain text lines on a pdf form if the user selects a particular option from a dropdown list on the form. The text I want to highlight is not text fields but just regular text in the document. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? You have to at least show an attempt.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far. Also, since you have an error, please include the full error traceback in the text of the question.

Comment: Will the text always be in the exact same position?